# Computer boots freezes when the ubuntu logo is showing

Tags: dual-boot

Problem: After selecting ubuntu from the GRUB menu, the logo is loaded and the dots  move as usual, then the screen freezes (the logo and dots stop moving).

OS version: Ubuntu 18.04.1

Specs:

```
 Model: Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming 
 Processors: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.5GHz
 Graphics Cards: Intel(R) HD Graphics 630, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
 RAM: 8192MB RAM
```

Partitions: 1Gb EFI, 20Gb root, 25Gb home, 10Gb swap, 400 unallocated, EFI is primary and the rest are logical.

Partitions order: EFI -> Root -> Home -> unallocated -> Swap

This is my first time dual booting so I could of made a mistake partitioning or something. I was actually able to get into Ubuntu GUI twice after a long load screen but couldn't get past after that. I don't think its a graphics problem since I haven't touched the drivers. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Actually the problem is lack of Nvidia drivers. The huge EFI is not a problem, just an absurd wast of space, only 100-300MB can have multiple OSes' bootloaders. 10GB of swap also excessive and with 18.04 NO NEED swap partition, it uses swapfile by default. And the drive is GPT, there are no primary/logical partitions, that's an old concept applicable only to MBR.